# Flutter Awesome Notification

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am using flutter awesome notification.

Wish to send a notification when the app is closed (not running in background). Just like an Alarm Clock, the notification will be send at specific time. Not push from external services like firebase.

Is there a way for doing that? Or I need another package like android_alarm_manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure  about awsome_notification but If you want to send a notification at some particular time of the day then you can use [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) This package will send you a notification if your app is closed or running

You need to use Scheduled notifications

But if you want to open a screen like an alarm and clock app do you need to use android_alarm_manager or some other plugin.